# Java EE web-development bitwise operation

Tags: jakarta-ee, bitwise-operators

I am working on a Java EE related web project using spring MVC and all.

General is it a good idea to use bitwise operators in web development? To hold more then 1 value in int value and then store it in the db?

For example if the user is only a user or it is user/admin/publisher/editor this may increase complexity?

In terms of complexity, is it advised to use bitwise operations in a Java EE website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We once tried doing this. This was looking a smart solution to start-with. We have created a Utility method that converts roles to bits and given the roles, it will set it to bits. Pretty much same as `chmod` in Unix.

Apparently, this was a non-intuitive way. And was not liked by many devs who just want to look-up database and get roles for a user.

We migrated from this approach to many-to-many mapping using three tables `users`, `user_roles` and `roles`. This was much cleaner.

I would suggest against bit-wise approach based on my personal experience.

Answer (score 0):

Java EE is irrelevant for this scenario. Why do you want to store more than 1 value in a int? You are making the application complex and hard to maintain.